# IPython.embed() in C++

Tags: c++, debugging, terminal, ipython

One of the things I love about python is how easy it is for me to debug a program by dropping an `IPython.embed()` line into my code and being able to have instant access to a terminal where I can check the values of all of my variables and perform tiny experiments to help me understand what's happening.

Lately I've been forced to dabble in C++ again, and although I'm loving the fact that everything is blazingly fast compared to naive python, I'm very bad at debugging things like segfaults. I'm averse to fancy IDEs with lots of confusing buttons and config and prefer to work with a simple text editor and a terminal.

I'm wondering if there are any terminal tools for debugging C++ in general and more specifically if anyone has seen anything at all like `IPython.embed()` in C++ (an interactive terminal you can drop into from the middle of your application).

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a command-line debugger like `gdb` (on Linux/Posix) or `lldb` (on MacOS/X).

Comment: Perhaps. What's the best resource you have on how to use gdb?

Comment: The best resource is Google -- go to google.com and enter the search term "gdb how-to", and read the results

Answer (score 0):

I have tested a workflow on linux

- embed python. https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html?highlight=py_initialize#c.Py_Initialize
- install ipython in the embedded python.
- run "import IPython; IPython.embed()" using PyRun_SimpleString.